# Using `pool` in an R Shiny package

Tags: r, shiny, connection-pooling, dbi

**How can I implement the use of a `pool` object in an R Shiny application structured like a package?**

I have structured my package [according to the layout](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-packaging.html) described by Hadley Wickham in "Mastering Shiny:

```
├── DESCRIPTION
├── NAMESPACE
├── R
  ├── app.R
  ├── modules.R
├── app.R
├── inst
└── tests
```

My Shiny application lives in `R/app.R` wrapped in a function called `callApp()`. The file `./app.R` simply calls `callApp()`.

The file `modules.R` represents actually many `.R` files that contain various functions and modules that comprise my Shiny application. My Shiny application looks like:

```
callApp <- function() {
  pool <- pool::dbPool(
    RMySQL::MySQL(),
    dbname = config::get("db_name"),
    host = config::get("db_host"),
    username = Sys.getenv("DB_USERNAME"),
    password = Sys.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
  )

  onStop(function() {
    pool::poolClose(pool)
  })

  header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = "title"
  )

  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      ....
  )

  body <- dashboardBody(
      ....
  )

  ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    modulefunction_server("module1")
    modulefunction_server("module2")
  }

  shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

As you can see, I am [using the `pool` package](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html) to connect to a MySQL datatbase and retrieve my data. I have placed `pool` at the top of the main `app.R` as described in the `pool` documentation. However, the problem I am having is in regards to my function `modulefunction_server()`:

```
modulefunction_server <- function(id) {

  shiny::moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

      dates <- datepicker_server("datepicker1")

      data <- getData(startDate = dates$date_from(),
                      endDate = dates$date_to())

   
      output$report <- DT::renderDT({
        make_table(data)
      })
   })
 }
```

It is actually the function `getData()` that requires the `pool` object. And `getData()` is stored in my `modules.R` file:

```
getData <- function(startDate, endDate) {
  sql <- getSQLFromFile(system.file("sql","query.sql", package = "mypackage"))
  query <- DBI::sqlInterpolate(pool, sql, startDate = startDate, endDate = endDate)
  DBI::dbGetQuery(pool, query)
}
```

When I run my application, I receive the error:

```
 error in evaluating the argument 'conn' in selecting a method for function 'sqlInterpolate': object 'pool' not found
```

**What is the recommended way of providing access to `pool` for all functions in a Shiny application?** I suppose I could pass `pool` as an argument to each of the functions, but this becomes very confusing and messy when attempting to retrieve data from `pool` via a function that is nested 5, 10, or 15 functions deep into a complex Shiny application.

UPDATE:

I have found [this related GitHub issue](https://github.com/rstudio/pool/issues/58) and have attempted to implement the solution:

I have moved `pool` into a `globals.R` file. I source `globals.R` at the beginning of my `app.R` I move the `onStop()` function into `shinyApp()` function:

```
callApp <- function() {
  source("R/globals.R")

  onStop(function() {
    pool::poolClose(pool)
  })

  header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = "title"
  )

  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
      ....
  )

  body <- dashboardBody(
      ....
  )

  ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    modulefunction_server("module1")
    modulefunction_server("module2")
  }

  shiny::shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, onStart = function() {
    onStop(function() {
       pool::poolClose(pool)
     })
  })
}
```

Unfortunately, while this allows `pool` to be visible to all functions, I am still left with a `Warning in (function (e)  : You have a leaked pooled object` every time I rebuild my package.

Comment: You might create the `pool` connection object within a `globals.R` file, which should be visible to all (modules or not).

Comment: I tried that but I get a couple of things - when I build my package, I get a warning: `Warning in (function (e)  : You have a leaked pooled object.` Additionally, when I try to run `callApp()`, my application boots up but then fails due to `Expired MySQL Driver` error.

Comment: "leaked pooled object" has nothing to do with this question. I get that warning frequently, and while I have not yet determined if it's a bug or just some network glitch or legit timeout ... it has been otherwise harmless in my deployed uses.

Comment: `leaked pool object` does not occur if `pool` is created at the top of `app.R`. So it seems related to this question. In fact, a `pool` contributor in the linked GitHub issue even states `pool` should never be created outside of `app.R` to avoid specifically the issue of leaking `pool` objects.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, *and you are still incorrect*. The **error** `object 'pool' not found` is about namespaces and finding objects; the **warning** `You have a leaked pooled object` is just a warning, and has nothing to do with finding objects (in fact, it indicates that a `pool` object was found). If you create `pool` inside or outside of `app.R`, you make a good point ... but the "leaked" warning has nothing to do with the "not found" error.

Comment: Seeing the same warning. Calling `dbGetQuery(pool, "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity where datname = 'mydb';")` returns 100+ process rows going back days. 

`shinyApp(...)` does contain arg `onStart = function(){onStop(function(){ poolClose(pool) })}`.

Comment: Also.. `dbGetQuery(pool, "SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'mydb';")` returns `Error: Failed to fetch row: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command`

Answer (score 1):

I chose to use a global variable, bearing in mind I'm working on a [Plumber application](https://www.rplumber.io/index.html), not a Shiny application and my application is quite simple so YMMV...

In the top level script where Plumber is instantiated

```
library(plumber)
library(pool)
library(RMySQL)

# store mysqlPool in global scope,
# knowing this is the entry-point of the application...
mysqlPool <<- dbPool(
    MySQL(),
    # connection info ...
)

pr <- plumb(
    # ...
)

pr$registerHooks(
    list(
        'exit' = function() {
            poolClose(mysqlPool)
        }
    )
)
```

Then in a lower level "library" script, to access the connection, something like this:

```
library(RMySQL)

conn <- poolCheckout(mysqlPool)

query <- sqlInterpolate(
    conn,
    "INSERT INTO my_table (field1, field2) VALUES (?field1, ?field2)",
    field1,
    field2
)

dbSendQuery(conn, query)

poolReturn(conn)
```